# Copying a directory from package in javafx

Tags: javafx, directory, copy-paste

I found nowhere a perfect answer. Let me have a directory or folder created inside the package of my java project. The location of the java project isn't static. I want to get the entire mentioned folder inside the package copied to another desired folder. I tried:

```
Path from = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("Folder").toString());
```

to get the path of the folder. But it didn't work...

How to do it now?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get good answers it is highly recommendable to post some code. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on tips for posting a good question.

Comment: People are taking too much time to answer...

Comment: There's no general way to do this. There are some fairly hacky approaches; you can examine the URL that is returned by `getClass().getResource(...)` and deduce if it is, e.g. a file-based or jar-based class loader. If it's file-based, you can use the java.io or java.nio api to scan the folder containing the classes; if it's jar-based, you can use the `java.util.zip` API to examine the content of the jar file. Of course, this doesn't handle custom class loaders, but those are rare. Frameworks like Spring have some of this functionality, so you could see how it is implemented there...

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to zip the folder up before deploying it to the project. Then you just have a single resource to get. You can then use the `java.util.zip` API to read from it and extract it on the fly to your other location.